# Pandas replacing string in one column leads to other column disappearing

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

New to Pandas, and Im doing something wrong. While running the bellow code to replace cells in column "data" that dont contain the string "fiels" with empty strings, instead of returning two columns (id, data), the whole of id column disappears with all rows starting with a delimiter instead. My intuition is because when I write back the chunk to csv I am only writing chunk_results which does not do anything on "id". The problem is I dont know how to solve it.

```
import pandas as pd
in_csv= "out.csv"
out_csv= "out_1.csv"
reader = pd.read_csv(in_csv, chunksize=100, sep='|', header=None, names=['id', 'data'], encoding='utf-8')
for chunk_df in reader:
    chunk_results = chunk_df['data'].astype(str).str.replace('^((?!field).)*$','', regex=True)
    chunk_results.to_csv(out_csv, mode='a', sep='|', encoding='utf-8', header=None, index=False)
```

**What I have tried:**
I guessed that I needed to create a `chunk_id = chunk_df['id']` and concat it with "chunk_results" to_csv but that just gave me an error. Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you looping over the dataframe instead of just processing it all at once?

Comment: You're setting `chunk_results` to just the `data` column of the dataframe.

Comment: Hi @Barmar Thank you for your reply. The file is 20 GB large and I dont have the resources to do the whole file at once, thats why Im doing it by chunks.  "You're setting chunk_results to just the data column of the dataframe. " I guessed as much but I dont know how to set it so that it doesnt just do `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the results back to the dataframe chunk's column. When you assign to `chunk_results` you're setting it to a dataframe with just the `data` column

```
chunk_df['data'] = chunk_df['data'].astype(str).str.replace('^((?!field).)*$','', regex=True)
chunk_df.to_csv(out_csv, mode='a', sep='|', encoding='utf-8', header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Barmar. thank you it worked! if anyone else have the same issue, do the above and then `chunk_df.to_csv`